# How to export/import OrientDB dumps and retain IDs

Tags: orientdb

When I export and re-import my OrientDB database, the IDs aren't retained (the import command seems to just assign new IDs), which makes the snapshotting kind of useless. How do I ensure that the IDs are kept consistent?

Comment: Try with -preserveClusterIDs = true https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Import.html

Comment: When I first tried with that flag, I got an error about a writeahead log file being missing. Somehow that error resolved itself when I tried again just now, but the IDs still don't match up.

Comment: In which version of OrientDB are you trying to import the export?

Comment: @idacrema Exporting from 2.2.31, importing to 2.2.31.

Answer (score 0):

Use: -preserveClusterIDs = true https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Import.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The RIDs are still getting changed upon export/import. Is there anything else I'm supposed to do to make it work?