# How does one use ___exportImportRIDMap in practice?

Tags: orientdb

I'm running into issues because OrientDB's EXPORT and IMPORT don't respect the integrity of RIDs (it is baffling to me that something meant to preserve data doesn't retain ids, but that's a topic for another time). [How to export/import OrientDB dumps and retain IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010303/how-to-export-import-orientdb-dumps-and-retain-ids)

According to the documentation, there is something called `___exportImportRIDMap` that is a mapping from the old RIDs to the new ones. How does one actually use this in practice? Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: Have you tried to update at the last version and retry with -preserveClusterIDs=true ?

Comment: @idacrema yes, I have